# IntelliJ shortcut for Run Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-idea2017

I recently changed Linux distros and I have forgotten what the keyboard shortcut is for making a run configuration in Kotlin in IntelliJ.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shift F10. Why don't you just look it up in the IntelliJ menu?

Comment: Because it's not their until you push ctrl+shift+f10. But thank you I eventually figured it out.

Comment: You can do short-ctrl-a to search for an action by name. Or double shift to search for anything by name.

Comment: Yeh I saw that when I was spamming buttons, but thanks now I know.

Comment: It's related to an IDE(a widely used one at that).

Answer (score 0):

Alt-Shift-F10 on Windows
Option-Shift-R on Mac OS

It may be helpful to print out the cheat sheet:

https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf